# Error with Android Gradle dependency version without '+'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

I was developing an Android app and got an interesting error.

I'm using the [Support Library v7 RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-recyclerview), and the provided link says that the latest version is 21.0.0. I had this code:

```
// in build.gradle
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'

// in RecyclerAdapter.java
@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {...}
```

The Studio said that the method *onAttachedToRecyclerView* was never used and did not override a method from its superclass. I've spent a few hours trying to find out how to solve the problem, and finally I tried changing my compile dependency to

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
// instead of
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
```

and it worked! But the Studio keeps highlighting this line in yellow saying that it is not recommended to use '+' in versions.

**So the question is:** why is there such an error when the version of support library is specified exactly (and according to the official website it's the latest one) and why is everything OK when it's not? I'm pretty much new to Android coding, so I want to make it clear how that works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using dynamic versions can cause trouble. Imagine this: a dependency is updated with some breaking changes - then your build may start failing without any code changes at all. This can be very hard to track down - I've had it happen to me, more so with third party libraries than Android framework stuff, however.

Comment: @stkent I understand this, the thing is that it only works with dynamic version and I wand to figure out why.

Comment: What buildToolsVersion are you using? Higher than 21.0.0 ?

Comment: @AHoneyBustard it's 21.1.2, is that the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the answer is simple. The version on the official site is not updated, it's actually 21.0.3. [Here](http://gradleplease.appspot.com/) is a great link to check libs versions, by the way.